# ionic push notifcation error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache-cordova, ionic

To fazendo um projeto ionic para receber notificações (android)  e estou usando o plugin do phonegap-plugin-push.

```
 var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "860498722229", icon : "icon"},
         "ios": {"alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"}, "windows": {} } );

    push.on('registration', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $rootScope.id = data.registrationId;
        $rootScope.$apply();
    });

    push.on('notification', function(data) {
        alert('Notificação acionada, agora deve-se implementar a navegação no app de acordo com os dados: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    });

    push.on('error', function(e) {
        alert('registration error: ' + e.message);
    });
```

Sim, eu já executei o comando que adiciona o plugin ao projeto 'ionic add phonegap-plugin-push'

**Sempre retorna o Erro 'PushNotification' is not defined.**

Comment: " 'PushNotification' is not defined" quer dizer que a referência para PushNotification não está definida. Você provavelmente esqueceu de importar o javascript dele na sua pagina.

Comment: vc deixou esse código dentro do $ionicPlatform.ready(function () { }); ? Ele deve ser executado dentro do ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recomendo o OneSignal, no site tem um exemplo de como implementar, segue exatamente o que esta escrito só trocando a Key. É bem confiável alem de ser free.

https://onesignal.com